# How to make a JBoss ESB configurable in the admin console

Tags: configuration, jboss, administration

The JBoss AS Admin Console has a "configuration" tab for ESBs deployed on the server.
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/Administration_Console_User_Guide-Updating_Resource_Configurations.html

It says that this is available for "resources that support configuration", but it is greyed out for an ESB service that I have written.

How can I make my service support configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code changes to the ESB RHQ plugin, that's not really possible.     The jbossesb RHQ plugin controls what's displayed there and there's nothing in your service configuration to allow run-time configuration through the admin-console.

If you're interested in changing that, you'd have to change the following files :

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/tools/jonplugin/src/main/java/org/jbosson/plugins/jbossesb/ServiceComponent.java

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/tools/jonplugin/as5/src/main/resources/META-INF/rhq-plugin.xml

Or submit a JIRA with a request of what service properties that you'd like to see configurable at runtime under JBoss ESB in the JBoss JIRA issue tracker :

https://issues.jboss.org/